# How to perform packet pair probing by sending multiple packets rather than just one pair ? (method for taking average)

Tags: sockets, network-programming, packets, moving-average, bandwidth-throttling

Generally in a packet pair estimation, you are supposed to send multiple bursts of packet pairs and take an average of the bandwidths.

Say, you send 4 packets, calculate the time difference between the first two packets(1&2), time difference between the next two packets(3&4). Calculate bandwidth for each of these two and then take average.

**Or**

Calculate the time difference between (1&2), time difference between (3&2), time difference between (4&3)... and then take an average out of these values.

Which is the right method for average?

Answer (score 0):

If you use packet pair to estimate bandwidth, use the first method.

Comment: Can you explain why the first method is preferred?